# pop external links on a new tab via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

The SEO "guru" at my job has asked me to find out if it'd be possible to implement some sort of .htaccess magic that would make all external links on our CMS pop out of the browser and open in a different tab/window.

Is this even remotely possible? I know it could be done with JS but it'd be a pretty complicated task to modify all pages/content on our site to make it happen.

Any and all help will be appreciated!

Comment: He isn't SEO guru if he's suggesting you to force popups on users.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that isn't possible via htaccess.

However, unless it is a weirdly coded CMS, then it should not be the complicated task you think.

A CMS will usually be built so that the content and template are in separate places, which should mean that you probably only need to update a single file in order to add code to the head of every page on the site, which could be a javascript to modify external links.  You should not have to touch the content.

Likewise, many CMSs will use a plug-in system allowing you to do this easily enough.

Also: A CMS will usually store content in a database, so a good database query could also replace all the links in one go.

Can't see how this could possibly help with SEO, mind!

Comment: Thank you Richard, I dont see the way this could be done via .htaccess either, but if it were possible, it´d be a single directive in a single place to take care of all instances...  As per not helping SEO... I am of the belief that the best SEO is good content, all other "optimizations" are useless (IMHO).  Thank you again!